# How to hide rough finished laminate/sunmica edges on furniture

Tags: cleaning, comfort, furniture, paint

I have recently did the furniture on my home. And they have not did the perfect job. All the sunmicas have rough edges at all the bends. They look very bad. Whole wardrobe and all the drawers have the black edge visible on white sheet. It looks dirty. Is there any way I can hide those edges? I have asked the painter who painted our walls, and he said if we color it with the paint, it will vanish over time. And that time can be a month also. So it is not a proper solution.

So any better way to hide black rough edges?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

normally, the exterior edges of a laminate-covered part are given a very shallow chamfer-cut at 45 degrees with a router using a tungsten-carbide edge trimming blade, and the exposed dark stripe is considered part of the design.

Barring that, you can cut edging strips of hardwood to attach as "faces" to hide the dark edge.

You can also buy strips of aluminum trim extrusion in an "L" profile, for covering the edges up.

However, these alternatives require some advance planning by the guy who attaches the laminate to the part you have built, and this does not seem to be done in your case. unfortunately, it looks like he didn't know how to properly do his job.

Answer (score -1):

You can rush down to hardware shop and buy white furniture tape to use as a covering.